# Class derived from a class with multiple inheritance in C++: the derived class is trying to call the root base class constructor

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, instantiation

I'm sorry if this feels like a cheap sequel to [my last question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64655841/2025742)

I have a diamond inheritance where `D` is derived from both `B` and `C`, who in turn are both derived (virtually) from `A`. `A`, `B` and `C` are abstract, and thanks to the answers to my previous questions the compiler is now aware of it and all is fine.

Now, I need to create a class `E` derived from `D`. As far as I know, normally the constructor `E::E` should call `D::D`, and it would be `D::D`'s job to call all of `A::A`, `B::B`, and `C::C`.

But my compiler really insists on having `E::E` call `A::A` itself.

Here is a simple example I made:

```
class A {                       //abstract
    protected:
        A(int foo) {}
        virtual void f() =0;
};

class B: public virtual A {     // abstract
    protected:
        B() {}
};

class C: public virtual A {     // abstract
    protected:
        C() {}
};

class D: public B, public C {   // concrete
    public:
        D(int foo, int bar) :A(foo) {}
        void f() {}
};

class E: public D {             // concrete
    public:
        E(int foo, int bar, int buz) :D(foo, bar) {}
};


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the compilation error:

```
$ g++ test.cpp
test.cpp: In constructor ‘E::E(int, int, int)’:
test.cpp:25:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
   25 |         E(int foo, int bar, int buz) :D(foo, bar) {}
      |                                                 ^
test.cpp:3:9: note: candidate: ‘A::A(int)’
    3 |         A(int foo) {}
      |         ^
test.cpp:3:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr A::A(const A&)’
    1 | class A {                       //abstract
      |       ^
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr A::A(A&&)’
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I know the virtual inheritance is correct and I know the compiler knows which classes I intend to be abstract and which I intend to be instantiable, because if I remove `class E`, the code compiles.

What am I missing?

Comment: The compiler is telling you what constructors of A are available.  You can see the one you defined A(int), plust the copy and move constructors.  By defining your own A constructor, you tell the compiler not to declare a default constructor.  See the example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

Answer (score 0):

> But my compiler really insists on having E::E call A::A itself.

Like I explained in anwer to your previous question: *"the constructor of the most derived class calls the constructor of the virtual base"*.

All non-abstract classes in a hierarchy that contains virtual bases must correctly initialise the virtual bases because they can potentially be instantiated as the most derived class. For example, if you create an instance of `E`, then it is the constructor of `E` that initialises the virtual base `A`.

In your code, the constructor of `E` attempts to use the default constructor of `A` by omitting the initialiser. But `A` is not default constructible, so the program is ill-formed.

> What am I missing?

The initialiser for the virtual base `A` in the constructor of `E`.

As far as I know, there is no way to delegate the construction to of the virtual base to another concrete base such as `D`.

Comment: It made sense in the other question, when e.g. `B` was deemed instantiable, that it must be able to initialize `A`. In the current example, I cannot think of a scenario where it would be necessary for `E` directly to initialize `A`.

Moreover, if I define `E`'s constructor as `E::E(...) :D(foo, bar), A(foo) {}`, what will happen with `D::D(...) :A(foo)`? Will there be two `A` instances?

Comment: @scozy `I cannot think of a scenario where it would be necessary for E directly to initialize A` It is unclear why you think so. E has a virtual base A (whether the base is direct is irrelevant) and it is concrete, therefore the scenario where E would have to initialise A directly is one where E is instantiated as the most derived object.

Comment: @scozy `what will happen with D::D(...) :A(foo)?` Like I wrote in the other answer: *"You simply must know that specific initialisation doesn't necessarily happen in case the concrete class is not the one which you are writing"*. To apply to this case, since D would not be the most derived class when instantiating E, D would not initialise A. That constructor of D would simply not initialise the base A and the initialiser you wrote for D would not be used.